# Sync MSA credentials with Win10 account

Tags: windows-10, passwords, sync, microsoft-account

I have an MSA (Microsoft Account) that I use to log into multiple Windows 10 computers and access via Remote Desktop. If I change my password via the website that does not update the Windows 10 account password. When I change the password for the Windows 10 account, that computer will be in sync with the MSA but not the others.

Can I force a computer to pull down the MSA credentials?

Comment: What are your synchronize settings like?  I have multiple devices connected to a single Microsoft Account and I have never had a problem changing the password to it and then logging into the account on those machines with that new password.

Comment: Sync Settings and all its sub-categories are on.

Comment: Is the problem isolated to just the RDP access or any attempt to log into account on the computer after you chnage the password?  Edit your question

Comment: On the devices themselves I usually use biometrics, but when using RDP only the old password works.

Comment: That doesn’t answer my question.